# Attempting to figure out angle from ray of a cone in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I'm working through *Shifrin's Multivariable Mathematics* and I've stumbled in attempting to figure out a specific statement. I have the following mapping:

[image]

Now one of the claims is that "if we fix $v = v_{0}$, the image is a ray making an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$." The claim of the image being a ray makes sense to me, but I was attempting to figure out how $\frac{\pi}{4}$ was arrived at. I tried to look at the cone through the point of view of an individual slice and use the trig functions available for right triangles with my $Z$ - axis serving as one of the two axis, but any manipulation in that manner doesn't get me the result.

I guess I'm wondering if it is possible to figure out the angle without having to resort to spherical coordinates?

Comment: $\sqrt {(u \cos (v))^2 + (u \sin (v))^2} = u$, So you have a right angled triangle with both sides as $u$ (other than hypotenuse).

Comment: I set up this equality and tried using one of the trig identities so, for instance let's say assuming height of $u$ as my adjacent side then I would get: $\cos(\theta) = \frac{u}{u}$ which would give me of course $\frac{\pi}{2}$...

Comment: No you get two sides as $u$. $z = u$ and $r = u$. So $tan \theta = \frac{u}{u}$.

Comment: Hypotenuse is $ \sqrt {u^2+u^2} = u \sqrt 2 $

Comment: isn't the hypotenuse: $\sqrt{u^{2}\cos^{2}(v_{0}) + u^{2}\sin^{2}(v_{0})} = \sqrt{u^{2}(\cos^{2}(v_{0}) + \sin^{2}(v_{0}))} =  u$?

Comment: that is the radius of the circular cross section of the cone. your triangle is with axis of the cone, the radius and the edge of the cone.

Comment: AH...now it makes sense....Thanks for your help. Did you want to put it in an answer form so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagram.

[image]

$r \leq \sqrt{u^2 \cos^2\theta + u^2 \sin^2\theta} = u$

So what you have is a right angled triangle with $\, l^2 = r^2 + z^2 = 2u^2 \implies l = u \sqrt2$.

Hence in this case, the angle between the axis of the cone and its outer edge is

$\displaystyle \tan^{-1} ({\frac{r}{z}}) = \tan^{-1} (1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.